# How to send JSON object to HTTPRequest and receive response in JSON

Tags: java, json, httpclient, httpresponse

I'm using JAVA language to accomplish this task.

I have an object created and I would like to send the data in JSON format as a POST request and receive response as JSON as well.

Here's my code.

```
CreditCardDetail creditCard = new CreditCardDetail("DummyPerson", "5433334344", 04, 2023, 567);

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(creditCard);

HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(URI.create(uri))
            .POST(BodyPublishers.ofString(json)).build();


HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, BodyHandlers.ofString());
```